# Link SQL Database to Date

Tags: c#, datetime, calendar

I am creating a C# program which is using a SQL database. I want to link values of dates to the calendar so that I can use them in the C# program. IE: 04/01/2010 = Monday, 05/01/2010 = Tuesday... etc 11/01/2010 = Monday, 12/01/2010 = Tuesday.

This in in the aim of showing a calendar view, that can be viewed in week lots, and move forward and backward in time by weeks.

Sorry for the terrible description (I'm sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just want to get the day of week?

```
DataTime.Parse(dateStr).DayOfWeek
```